# I don't want ListView updated when add item to the top

Tags: android, android-listview

1. The ListView shows 10 items;
2. I add 3 items to the top of Adapter

**Expected**:
Only when I scroll up, the 3 new items shows.

**Actual**:
The 3 items display immediately, pull the old items down.

Answer (score 0):

The ListView will continue displaying the same *position* after an update. To compensate for the new items in the list, you will need to scroll to the old top item's updated position.

```
listView.setSelection(oldTopItemPosition);
```

Comment: seems not work. My code, ` int firstVisiblePosition = listView.getFirstVisiblePosition();
            adapter.addMessageItemsToTop(messages);
            if (addToTop){
                listView.setSelection(firstVisiblePosition + messages.size());
            }
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`

Comment: Call setSelection after notifyDataSetChanged.